# parsing a json string with duplicate keys in ruby

Tags: ruby, json

i have a json with duplicate keys as below:

```
{"a":{
"stateId":"b",
"countyId":["c"]
},"a":{
"stateId":"d",
"countyId":["e"]
}}
```

When i use `JSON.parse` or `JSON(stirng)`, it parses and gives me the key with values `d, e`. I need to parse the json such that it it avoids parsing the same key twice and has `b, c` values for the key `'a'` instead of `'d', 'e'`.

Comment: Your JSON string is not valid JSON. You need to fix that before attempting to parse it.

Comment: it is a fairly huge file with so may duplicates and it has been sent from some other data source that i dont even know. Is there any software to remove the duplicates in this json file?

Comment: Nothing that I know of. You'd probably need a custom-built parser to handle this.

Comment: oh, ok thank you, i will ask the person who gave me the json to help me out.

Comment: @MikeW, this is perfectly valid JSON. I've had this exact same problem before and I am wondering how to solve this as well. I don't know of any Ruby-based JSON parsers that will detect and throw an exception for duplicate keys, rather than simply replacing the first key with the second.

Comment: @davogones - technically you are correct: this is syntactically correct. However, it's functionally flawed because every parser I know will overwrite the first values with the second. Without some storage mechanism to cross check the incoming data that's all the parsers can do. To unpick this you'd need either to fix the problems in the original dataset, or write a custom parser that will read and understand the incoming datastream while storing and cross-checking the data for duplicates. It can be done, but it's not trivial.

Comment: @MikeW, everything you say is correct. But this does not mean the question is invalid. It's a common problem and there is no good solution that I'm aware of. One does not always have control over the JSON they work with (for example if they are working with a 3rd-party API).

Comment: to remove duplicates, just paste your json into [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com), it worked for your example.

Answer (score 7):

There is a way. Instead of using the ususal Hash class for parsing JSON objects, use a slightly modified class, which can check if a key already exists:

```
class DuplicateCheckingHash < Hash
  attr_accessor :duplicate_check_off
  def []=(key, value)
    if !duplicate_check_off && has_key?(key) then
      fail "Failed: Found duplicate key \"#{key}\" while parsing json! Please cleanup your JSON input!"
    end
    super
  end
end

json = '{"a": 1, "a": 2}'  # duplicate!
hash = JSON.parse(json, { object_class:DuplicateCheckingHash }) # will raise

json = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
hash = JSON.parse(json, { object_class:DuplicateCheckingHash })
hash.duplicate_check_off = true # make updateable again
hash["a"] = 42 # won't raise
```

Comment: think its possible to just concatenate subsequent duplicate key values to the value of the 1st?

Comment: Perhaps. But, unless I misunderstand you, that wasn't my question...
My question was whether you can combine the two parse() calls into one parse() call and still get an exception if there are duplicate keys...

Comment: A nice suggestion (thanks claus) now gives a way that only uses a single parse call.

Comment: @JonJagger Wow, you improved it even more! Thanks for your initial answer which got me on the right track in the beginning. This little trick that we now got here is just beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the format of your string.  If it's as simple as you posted:

```
require 'json'

my_json =<<END_OF_JSON
{"a":{
"stateId":"b",
"countyId":["c"]
},"a":{
"stateId":"d",
"countyId":["e"]
},"b":{
"stateId":"x",
"countyId":["y"]
},"b":{
"stateId":"no",
"countyId":["no"]
}}
END_OF_JSON


results = {}

hash_strings = my_json.split("},")

hash_strings.each do |hash_str|
  hash_str.strip!

  hash_str = "{" + hash_str if not hash_str.start_with? "{"
  hash_str += "}}" if not hash_str.end_with? "}}"

  hash = JSON.parse(hash_str)

  hash.each do |key, val|
    results[key] = val if not results.keys.include? key
  end

end

p results

--output:--
{"a"=>{"stateId"=>"b", "countyId"=>["c"]}, "b"=>{"stateId"=>"x", "countyId"=>["y"]}}
```